# Executar scripts de diferentes diretorios

Tags: python

Tenho uma série de rotinas para executar diariamente no Python.

Gostaria de um código para executar todas em um scipts apenas.

```
Ex:

#rotina 1
r1 = C:\Users\rotina1\rotina1.py
r1.execute

#rotina 2
r2 = C:\Users\rotina2\rotina2.py
r2.execute
```

Existe algo do tipo? Me ajudaria muito.

Comment: faz um script do powershell

Answer (score 0):

Para rodar scripts Python utilizando outro script Python você pode utilizar a biblioteca os.

```
#importando biblioteca
import os
```

Com a função os.system() é possível utilizar comandos do sistema operacional:

```
os.system('<<comando>>')
```

logo para a execução dessas rotinas pode ser executada com o código abaixo:
*WINDOWS
import os

```
r1 = 'C://Users//rotina1//rotina1.py'
r2 = 'C://Users//rotina2//rotina2.py'

rotinas = [r1, r2]

for r in rotinas:
    os.system(f'python {r}')
```

Para sistemas UNIX o comando provavelmente será necessário específicar a versão do python instalada no seu computados, ficando da seguinte maneira:

Exemplo Python3.X:

```
import os

r1 = 'C://Users//rotina1//rotina1.py'
r2 = 'C://Users//rotina2//rotina2.py'

rotinas = [r1, r2]

for r in rotinas:
    os.system(f'python3 {r}')
```

Espero ter ajudado :)